# Filename too long in Git for Windows 11, error only when remote attached

Tags: git

This relates to Git (version 2.43.0.windows.1) running on Windows 11 (as of 04-Jan-2024). A barebones repo with only 2 text files placed in a very deep nested directory structure, total path exceeding 260 chars (more like 500 chars), example:
`...\some_very\long\directory\nesting_over_260_chars\helloworld`

All the steps to overcome windows filename length restrictions have been applied, see similar [this stackoverflow ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows). That worked except, when cloning from a remote or adding a remote; errors are thrown. This only happens when the path > 260 chars **and** when the repo has a **remote**, or a remote is being added.

Actions and their outcomes:

- Pass: create a new repo using `git init`.
- Pass: existing repo, with no remote, commits work fine
- Fail: cloning a repo from a remote (Bitbucket/GitHub), even with a barebones project (2 text files). Examples of commands attempted, it does not matter to restrict clone depth, all fail with error `helloworld/.git/config': Filename too long`:

  - `git clone https://myuser@bitbucket.org/devexamples/helloworld.git`
  - `git clone -c core.longpaths=true https://myuser@bitbucket.org/devexamples/helloworld.git`
- Fail: attempting to attach a remote to an existing project, example `git remote add origin <SOME URL>`
- Pass: clone repo to a shallow path `d:\dev\helloworld`, remote is attached
- Fail: Exact copy/move the cloned repo directory (remote is attached) from a shallow path `d:\dev\helloworld` to the long path. Error, when running any git command, example: `git status`:

`fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

#### Windows filename max length updates implemented

The instructions on [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows) were followed and can confirm:

- git global and system config contains and appear via `config --list`. (This was also applied/removed to the repo level config too)

```
[core]
    longpaths = true
```

- the windows registry key

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"LongPathsEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

- Group Policy is updated to enabled for:
  `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable Win32`
- machine hard (left shift held down) rebooted several times
- no filenames individually exceed 100 chars
- the total path including folders and file do not exceed 500 chars, way less than the 4096 limits

Comment: Let's hope things changed since this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308002/724039